# How to get tourist destination with in a city using Places SDK for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am beginner to Android and couldn't understand documentation of Places SDK for Android. I want to get all tourist destination within a city. So if anyone can help that would be great help.

I have tried searching tutorials but most of them are outdated which uses Places API which doesn't works on Android now.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is currently possible to get tourist destinations from Android SDK.
Though you can get tourist places within the city using [Places Web Services API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=new+york+city+tourist+interest&language=en&key=API_KEY`

Make a get request to this URL. The response that you will get is similar to [New York tourist places](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=h_NyW4HVDdGo9QOYw6PgBg&q=new+york+tourist+places&oq=new+york+touris&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l10.251.4738.0.6589.18.16.1.0.0.0.228.2200.0j6j5.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.12.2241.0..35i39k1j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i131i67k1j0i10k1.0.2VHxO6B-UNs)  this google search.

Also, you can check the json response on the query of this type from [Places Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). You can then parse json.